# Direction of current in a wire connecting two conducting loops placed concentrically in a time varying magnetic field which is into the plane of paper

Tags: current, electromagnetism

Figure shown plane figure made of a conductor located in a magnetic field along the inward normal to the plane of the figure. The magnetic field starts increasing. What will be the direction of current at point R ?

I know currents in both the loops will be anticlockwise, but I am not sure about the direction at R.

[image]

Comment: Current flows in closed paths. What's the closed path containing R?

Comment: @sweber I can't find any closed path. So I suspect no current should not flow through R. However, the confusion I am facing is that the outer loop has a higher potential compared to inner loop due to Faraday's law. How is it possible a wire that connects two points having different potentials has no current flowing through it ?

Comment: Correct, no current. There is also no general potential between the two loops, like there is no general potential between two batteries. Connecting one terminal of the first with one of the second battery brings them to the same potential, and only then, you will have a potential between the unconnected terminals. I.e. without R, there could never be a potential between P and Q.

Answer (score 0):

Think about a regular AC mains transformer with two isolated secondary windings. You can interconnect the secondaries like this: -

[image]

To obtain the same voltage but twice the amps or, you can connect them like this: -

[image]

To get twice the voltage and the same amps.

There is no inherent current flow from one winding to the other whether the secondaries are shorted or open circuit - they are isolated.

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't learn about AC circuits yet. It would be better if you could explain using the figure given in the original question.

Comment: That diagram with the increasing flux is an ac circuit. Induction doesn't happen with static fields only changing or alternating fields. In magnetics of course.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question depends upon assumptions that are not given in the question.

A time varying H (or B) field is always associated with an E field. It is assumed that the elements in this problem are *conductive*. If there is a net E field in any part of these conductors, current will flow, in accordance with the microscopic version of Ohm's law

$$\vec{J} = \sigma\vec{E}$$

This current will have at least two effects. First, it will affect the total H (or B) field. The total H field consists of two components, the applied H field, and the reaction H field created by the "induced" current. Second, if the divergence of the current density field is non-zero, which will be the case where there is no closed circuit path, the charge density will change with time. A non-zero charge density will affect the total E field, which in turn will affect the current and the H field.

So, we either have to concern ourselves with the reaction fields, or treat them as negligible, and the question does not specify whether or not to assume the reaction fields are negligible.

Let us for the moment treat the reaction fields as negligible, and simply look at the E field associated with a changing B field.

According to the Maxwell-Faraday equation

$$\nabla \times \vec{E} = -\frac{d\vec{B}}{dt}$$

We are given that

$$\frac{d\vec{B}}{dt} \ne 0$$

so

$$\nabla \times \vec{E} \ne 0$$

but we are not given any more information about \$\frac{d\vec{B}}{dt}\$. Lets assume for the moment that it is the same everywhere on the plane of the page given in the question,

$$\frac{d\vec{B}}{dt}=K$$.

Given that assumption, the curl of the E field is constant everywhere in this plane. An E field of constant curl looks like a vortex as in [this image from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_%28mathematics%29#/media/File:Uniform_curl.svg)

[image]

Where is the element R from our original question in relation to the center of this vortex?

[image]

We don't know, as we are not given enough information in the original question.

However, if

1. we ignore any reaction effects caused by the conductive elements in our problem, and
2. we assume that element R lies on a line radial to the vortex,

then there will be no induced voltage in the element R, because the E field lines will be perpendicular to R.

However, if we assume that element R lies on a line circumferential with respect to the vortex, there *will* be an induced voltage across R.

If the electric field is constant, due to the 2nd derivative of the H field being \$0\$, the induced voltage across R will cause a temporary current which results in a non-zero charge density in (or on the surface of) our conductive elements. However, if the 2nd derivative of the H field is non-zero, for example because there the H field varies sinusoidally in time, then an alternating current will flow through R. That is, it will act as an antenna. The H field is perpendicular to R because it lies perpendicular to the plane of the page. The Poynting vector is askew to R because R is not on a line radial to the vortex.

Conclusion. We have found at least two scenarios with opposite results. One scenario in which there is no induced voltage in element R, and another in which there is an alternating E field induced in element R. But the original question does not give us sufficient information to choose between the many possible solutions of this problem.